# How to enable SSL for LDAP with Apache Directory Studio?

Tags: ldap

I am using Apache Directory Studio for testing LDAP services for an application. I am lost in configuring the LDAP with SSL.

So far I've tried:

1. Started ApacheDS with port 10389 (ldap://) and also on 10636 (ldaps://)

Here's the screenshot of ldap config in Apache Directory studio:
[image]

Then I followed the instructions as mentioned here: [How to enable SSL](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/3.3-enabling-ssl.html)

I generated the keys using [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html):

```
C:\LDAP\keys>keytool -genkey -keyalg "RSA" -dname "
mojo,cn=com" -alias mojo -keystore mojo1.ks -storepass secret -validity 3650
```

and then I am using this key in Apache Directory Studio (and restarting the LDAP server), I end up with this error:
[image]

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is with Apache Directory Studio:

In the path use `/` instead of `\` in the path.

For instance, if key is present in `C:\keys.ks` then it should be entered as `C:/keys.ks`

This is not a good user experience.

P.S: this issue is reported at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-908